# unable to use custom cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am not able to make out whatrs wrong with this piece of code all I am trying to do is use custom table cell 'AlertCell' when device is in portrait mode and 'AlertCellLandScape' if device is in 'landscape' mode.

its saying cell is undeclared and inside the condition check its saying unused cell

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
UITableViewCell *cell;

if (isPortraitMode) 
{
    AlertsTableCell *cell = (AlertsTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
}

else {
    AlertsTableCellLandScape *cell = (AlertsTableCellLandScape *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
}






if (cell == nil) {
   // cell = [[[AlertsTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if (isPortraitMode) {
        cell = [[[AlertsTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
    }
    else {
        cell = [[[AlertsTableCellLandScape alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] autorelease];
    }
}
```

Please shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you reloading table when you rotate device?You have to reload table when you rotate device because by default it will not called.

Comment: This won't solve your problem (Terrys answer will) but if you have different cells you have to use different cell identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this instead, you have issues with how you declared the types of the cell, but this should work unless you are accessing the cell-reference outside if-else portrait block.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

if (isPortraitMode) {
    AlertsTableCell *cell = (AlertsTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[AlertsTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
    }

    return cell;

} else {
    AlertsTableCellLandScape *cell = (AlertsTableCellLandScape *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[AlertsTableCellLandScape alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] autorelease];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a scope issue. You're declaring cell inside your if/else, so it doesn't exist outside of them.

Declare cell before your if/else, then assign it inside.

Comment: I declared cell as UItableViewCell outside if but even after that I was unable to use my custom cells outside the if/else block

Comment: of course you are unable to do this. The UITableViewCell doesn't know about those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to give it the correct identifier in xcode:

```
if (isPortraitMode) 
{
    AlertsTableCell *cell = (AlertsTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AlertCell"];
}

else {
    AlertsTableCellLandScape *cell = (AlertsTableCellLandScape *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AlertCellLandScape"];
}
```

and to set it correctly (fil the Identifier field) in IB for the respective cells

Comment: I tried to do this but my cell is unable to recognized the customcell properties like lables and textfield

Comment: What is your cellForRowAtIndexPath returning?

Comment: @ankit-sachan : What is your cellForRowAtIndexPath returning?

Comment: @invocation: program crashes, I am asking how to deal with orientation issue and propose a solution pertaining to that

Comment: @ankit-sachan to get to the orientation problem you should first be sure that you implement correctly the UITableViewDelegate. Try showing the table correctly in Portrait mode and then add the orientation testing/conditional building the interface.